# How do I fix an IndentationError

Tags: python

I started learning `flask` a few days ago from the e-book flask framework cookbook.
I am confused about the following error.

```
File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
  from my_app import app
File "/home/kenosis/flask_app/my_app/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  from my_app.product.views import product_blueprint
File "/home/kenosis/flask_app/my_app/product/views.py", line 10
   def home():
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

This is my `views.py`

```
from werkzeug import abort
from flask import render_template
from flask import Blueprint
from my_app.product.models import PRODUCTS
product_blueprint = Blueprint('product', __name__)
@product_blueprint.route('/')
@product_blueprint.route('/home')
    def home():
        return render_template('home.html', products=PRODUCTS)
@product_blueprint.route('/product/<key>')
    def product(key):
        product = PRODUCTS.get(key)
        if not product:
            abort(404)
        return render_template('product.html', product=PRODUCTS)
```

and then this is my init

```
from flask import Flask
from my_app.product.views import product_blueprint
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(product_blueprint)
product_blueprint = Blueprint('main', __name__, template_folder='templates')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please correctly format your question

Comment: In python, indentation matters. You don't indent after a decorator (`@product_blueprint.route('/home')`).

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is very important in Python. Do not indent after the decorator

```py
from flask import render_template, abort
from flask import Blueprint
from my_app.product.models import PRODUCTS

product_blueprint = Blueprint('product', __name__)

@product_blueprint.route('/')
@product_blueprint.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', products=PRODUCTS)

@product_blueprint.route('/product/<key>')
def product(key):
    product = PRODUCTS.get(key)
    if not product:
        abort(404)
    return render_template('product.html', product=PRODUCTS)
```

Comment: indent solve.. and now i got error : ImportError: cannot import name 'Abort' from 'werkzeug' , is long journey to learn python... T.T

Comment: `abort` is imported from flask, not `werkzeug`. See edited response.